# Clarifying what is meant by “complete path coverage”

Tags: testing

In class, we were given this static method which we are asked to test. The method is supposed to (but won’t always) return the same integer value that was given as input.

```
static int identity(int x) {
        if (20 <= x && x <= 30) {
            x /= 2;
        }
        if (5 <= x && x <= 15) {
            x *= 2;
        }
        return x;
    }
```

The question asks us to create the minimum set of tests that has “complete path coverage”. Since there are two conditional statements, you would expect to generate 2^n tests, which is 4 in this instance. However, it is impossible to create a test where the first condition is true and the second condition is false. Does this mean that the minimum number of tests that has “complete path coverage” is 3?

Answer (score 0):

From the POV of a tester, I would look at the edges of your ranges to determine your test coverage. You don't want to just make sure that the if statements are executed - you want to check the boundaries of the ranges as well as one input within the range.

Given this, I would test the following inputs and expect the following outputs:

```
| input | output |
| 19    | 19     | (just outside first boundary minimum)
| 20    | 20     | (just inside first boundary minimum)
| 24    | 24     | (value within the range)
| 30    | 30     | (just inside first boundary maximum)
| 31    | 31     | (just outside first boundary maximum)
| 4     | 4      | (just outside second boundary minimum)
| 5     | 10     | (just inside second boundary minimum)
| 10    | 20     | (value within the range)
| 15    | 30     | (just inside second boundary maximum)
| 16    | 16     | (just outside second boundary maximum)
```

If you want to read more, google boundary testing.